# Only show DIV if on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very long HTML page with 2000+ products. On old computers the page would freeze due to a lack on memory. If I change the CSS display to none to 50% of divs, the performance increases a lot.

So I wanted to have the display:block only when the div is onscreen.

I have tried to use the following script : http://www.teamdf.com/web/jquery-element-onscreen-visibility/194/

I have updated the **on** method to **bind** but it still doesn't work.

Would there be an elegant way to create a css class that only appear when on screen ?

Comment: Can I just ask, in what world is a page with 2000 products on it at once useful to anybody? Surely you should be performing some kind of server side filtering in the first place. I would say that having 2000+ products on a single HTML page would be the right solution perhaps 0.0001% of the time.

Comment: agree. I am currently changing the way I'll tackle this pb. Thanks a lot for pushing me realizing that !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the [onScreen Plugin](http://silvestreh.github.io/onScreen/).
This is how you would initialize it:

```
$('.product-item').onScreen({
    doIn: function() {
        // Do something to the matched elements as they come in
        $(this).addClass('visible');
    },
    doOut: function() {
        // Do something to the matched elements as they get off scren
        $(this).removeClass('visible');
    }
});
```

But I would definitely consider loading the products through ajax while the user scrolls.
This is called lazyloading and is a common technique.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have added the following line to load the js : <script type="text/javascript" src="http://silvestreh.github.io/onScreen/lib/jquery.onscreen.min.js"></script> but when I add you code and add the product-item class to my divs it doesn't work. Do you know if I need anything else (I have already jquery).

Comment: You should download the plugin to a local folder, I can imagine that hotlinking is not allowed. Also be sure to set the visibility of .product-item to `hidden`or the `display` property to `none`. The class .visible would then have a property which makes the item visible